# Use one JavaScript function with two forms

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, forms

I have a JavaScript function for checking form input which sends an AJAX request to a PHP script. Here is the HTML:

```
<form method="post" id="textform35" action="insert_text.php">
    <textarea id="text" cols="80" rows="3" placeholder="forecast text"></textarea>
    <input type=hidden id="text_old" value="">
    <input type=hidden id="sin_type" value="short">
    <input type=hidden id="den" value="0">
    <input type=hidden id="grad" value="България-в">
    <input type=hidden id="span" value="1">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit" onclick="validate_sendForm()">
</form>

<form method="post" id="textform70" action="insert_text.php">
    <textarea id="text" cols="80" rows="12" placeholder=" >> "></textarea>
    <input type=hidden id="text_old" value="">
    <input type=hidden id="sin_type" value="short">
    <input type=hidden id="den" value="0">
    <input type=hidden id="grad" value="България-в">
    <input type=hidden id="span" value="1">
    <input type="button" name="Submit" value="Запази" onclick="validate_sendForm()">
</form>
```

As you can see, there are two forms with identical elements but with different `id`s.

The function `validate_sendForm()` is as below:

```
function validate_sendForm() {
    var text=document.getElementById("text").value;
    var y=document.getElementById("text_old").value;

    if (text==y) {
        if (y=='') {
            alert("some text ");
            return false;
        } else {
            alert("another text ");
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        var city_id   = document.getElementById("grad").value;
        var fore_code = document.getElementById("sin_type").value;
        var date_for  = document.getElementById("den").value;
        var date_span = document.getElementById("span").value;

        var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
        var params="grad="+city_id+"&den="+date_for+"&span="+date_span+"&sin_file="+fore_code+"&tekst="+text;
        xhttp.open("POST", "insert_text.php", true);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-length", params.length);
        xhttp.setRequestHeader("Connection", "close");

        xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
                alert(xhttp.responseText);
            }
        }

        xhttp.send(params);
    }
};
```

How can I use the function with both forms? Now it takes the values of the first form and never looks at the second one. I suppose I have to use "this" but have no idea where or how. Please, don't suggest that I use jQuery because I can not.

Comment: You are using id attribute with same value...id should be unique

Comment: Yes, otherwise I won't be able to use the function. I think there is a way to point to the form which has a unique id. That is what I am looking for.

Comment: Does you have to submit both form separately ? Or both should get submit on click of any one button ?

Comment: Separately. No need to do it with one button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved my problem by passing the sum of two random numbers as a parameter to `validate_sendForm()`. Then I concatenated the number to all element `id` s in the form, thus making them unique.

I will mark this as "accepted answer" not because it is the most elegant or correct one, but simply because that is what worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

First of all I suggest you to change the input's `id` to `class` because an `id` must be unique.

now, in your case a good solution would be passing as param the form id to the function:

`onclick="validate_sendForm('textform35')"` ,
`onclick="validate_sendForm('textform70')"`

and then, selecting it inside the function, get the form inputs.

```
function validate_sendForm(_id){

    var formEl = document.getElementById(_id);

    // if you changed the input's id to class..:
    var inptEl_textOld = formEl.querySelector("input.text_old");
    var inptEl_sinType = formEl.querySelector("input.sin_type");
    var inptEl_den     = formEl.querySelector("input.den");
    // ...
}
```

---

An other way is to pass `this` (instead of the form id) to your function which is the reference of `<input type="button"` you clicked.

like: `onclick="validate_sendForm(this)"`

and then take the element you need browsing the element's parents:

```
function validate_sendForm(_btn){

    var formEl = _btn.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector("form");

    // ...
}
```

Comment: To select the form inside the function can I do : document.forms["textform70"]["text"].value ?

Comment: no, `document.forms` is an array, you have to browse it with indexes https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/API/Document/forms 
 , anyway if you have the `id` you can just get it using `getElementById`

Comment: I tried your first suggestion. Changed all "id" into "class" in  HTML then copied your code and added a simple `alert(inptEl_text); ` to display the result. In console it says `TypeError: formEl.querySelector(...) is null`  regardless of what I type  in textarea.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $('input[name=Submit]').click(function(){
            var id = $(this).parents('form').attr('id');
        // submit form as per the id
    });
});
```

You can get the id of the form on click using jquery. on basis of that id you can get the fields of the perticular form. If you don't want to use jquery, you can pass parameter 'this' from the method as already suggested in one of the comment. With this parameter you can discriminate the forms.